# Variance of multinomial and Dirichlet-multinomial distributions

Tags: sampling, multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, conjugate-prior, overdispersion

I have an application where I would like to sample from a multinomial distribution, but I am concerned that the variance will be too low. As an alternative, I am considering the Dirichlet-multinomial distribution, but I am concerned that the variance will be too high.

The variance of the $Multinomial(p_1,...,p_k,n)$ distribution for the $i$th outcome is $np_i(1-p_i)$. The variance of the $Dirichlet-Multinomial(p_1,...p_k,n)$ distribution is $\frac{n-1}{2}np_i(1-p_i)$ (provided that $\sum_ip_i=1$).

In my application, $n$ is often more than 100, in which case the variance of the Dirichlet-multinomial distribution is greater than 50 times the variance of the multinomial distribution for the same outcome. I have not tested the fit of the two distributions to my data, but I suspect that this is too large.

Is there a similar distribution with variance between the two? Is there a similar distribution with a parameter that scales the variance for fixed $p_1,...,p_k$ and $n$? Is there an alternative solution to my problem?

Comment: Maybe if you could state your real problem?

Comment: Look at the neagtive multinomial distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_multinomial_distribution  it gives more flexible modelling of the variance